# keras CNN can't recognize images with one channel

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a `CNN model` on my data which is a set of `gray-scale` images generated from numpy arrays by `OpenCV`, the images are `75*70` pixels. I got the following error:

```
    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_25_input to have 
    shape (64, 64, 1) but got array with shape (64, 64, 3)
```

here is my code:

```py
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64,64,1), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
#classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
#classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 750, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')


classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         samples_per_epoch = 525,
                         nb_epoch = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         nb_val_samples = 225)
```

my pictures have only one channel but still, I get this input shape error,
can anyone help me, please?

Edit:
I found the answer in `keras documentation` , that `ImageDataGenerator` default `color_mode` is `rgb`, so I changed it to `grayscale`, it solved the problem of `input shape`
the code looks like this ;

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train',
                                                 target_size = (64,64),
                                                 color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')
```

however, I got another error:
`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_87 to have shape (750,) but got array with shape (0,)`
which I can't figure out ...!!

Comment: Take one picture from your data and print it shape, i think that you miss grayscale  some pics. Try to cv2.imread(img_path, 0) all of them again.

Comment: the thing is I should provide an input shape in the conv. layer, shouldn't I?

Comment: If you want work on grayscale picture, use cv2.cvt to convert all your data into grayscale with 1 channel. If you want work with original data, change input_shape to (64,64,3)

Comment: I want to work with graeyscale images , actually I generated these images from 2D arrays so each pixel has only one value, so i think they should have only one channel. Besides, I chanaged the input shape to (64,64,3), i got another error : ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_47 to have shape (750,) but got array with shape (0,)

Comment: `classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64,64,3), activation = 'relu',  dim_ordering='tf'))` try this.

Comment: i used the above code but got this error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_53 to have shape (750,) but got array with shape (0,)

Comment: try thí Conv2D instead of Convolution2D, and no need input_shape https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using .reshape(64,64,1) to make sure that your images are in one channel

Comment: thanks, @Harshit Gupta, should I do it like this: train_datagen.reshape(64,64,1) ??